# How to attach actionscript file to mxml?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

```
mxmlc HelloWorld.mxml
```

How can I import the *.as file while compiling the mxmlc?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html Look for `source-path`

Comment: I get an error that only one source is allowed in the filespec, which i need to use the -library-path, or the source-path commands?>

Comment: Both flags can be used side by side, but they serve a different purpose; library-path is for including compiled code from a separate library (a .swc). The main class (HelloWorld.mxml) _has_ to be the last argument though; perhaps there's something wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

See below sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    minWidth="955" 
    minHeight="600"
    >

    <fx:Script
        source  = "FooScript.as"/>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button x="355" y="515" width="218" id="btn" label="परिचय"/>

</s:Application>
```

Please note that Foo.mxml and FooScript.as are in the same package.

Comment: [Yes but then how to call a function of `FooScript.as` from the Mxml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54855298/2284570) ?

Comment: @user2284570 Just call the function in the event handler. Ex: <s:Button click="myFunction(event)" />

Comment: But as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54855298/2284570) then there is an error stating `"myFunction(event)"`is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I am just wondering why can't you use the **import** or **include** command inside your MXML code.

```
include "your_script.as";

import yourpackage.your_script.myFunc;
```

Docs -> http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff4.html