# How to include an actionscript function from an external file in flex4/MXML/Spark?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4.5, mxml

It turns out that’s it’s impossible to declare a class inside a embedded `<fx:Script><![CDATA[` so it turns I need to put and include the actionscript code inside an external Sourcefile. The error is commented out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="1955" minHeight="1600">
    <fx:Script source="URLRequest.as" />
    <s:layout>
        <s:BasicLayout />
    </s:layout>
    <s:Panel x="0" y="0" width="955" height="600" title="Bypass">
        <s:layout>
            <s:BasicLayout />
        </s:layout>
        <s:Label x="1" y="1" text="Please enter the ɢɪᴛ repository ʜᴛᴛᴘ ᴜʀʟ :"/>
        <s:TextInput x="224" y="1" width="726" id="txtName" text="http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/flashredirect/?http"/>
        <s:Button x="1" y="12" label="ɢɪᴛ push !" click="send()"/> <!-- Undefined Method method error -->
    </s:Panel>
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

and in URLRequest.as :

```
final public class MyClass {
    // some stuff
}
public function send():void {
    var request:Myclass=new Myclass(txtName.text);
    // Some stuff with 
}
```

So the question is simple but I couldn’t found the answer anywhere. At least not with for mxml with Spark.
`send()` doesn’t need to be in a class and as you can see is outside a class. But it needs to use a custom class.

So how can I call `send()` from URLRequest.as ?

Comment: what you posted is very confusing: 1. You should avoid creating a class named `URLRequest` just to avoid explicitly casting and other shenanigans as there already is an as3 class named [URLRequest](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html), 2. `MyClass` doesn't seemed to be defined. Please make it easier to for yourself and other people to understand/test your code

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I made an error : post edited. In reality I found a security issue through partial re-implementation in Urlrequest and hence I forgot to change the name. Should no longer be confusing

Comment: File name should be the same as the class name. If your class name is **MyClass** then the file name must be **MyClass.as** and none other. Also, your class file has the wrong structure: the top definition is **package** then **class** and then methods are defined inside the class, not outside.

Comment: @Organis except that as you read the `send()`method is not in a class and as far I understand this is not needed. As far I understand, I also do not need to declare a package. Correct me if I am wrong though.

Comment: Each AS3 class is a separate file. An AS3 class file is totally different from include-able ActionScript file. If you want to work with classes, then you are doing it wrong as I pointed out above. If you just need a piece of ActionScript code in a separate file so that you can include it in **fx:Script** tag, then you shouldn't declare a class in that file.

Comment: @Organis the `send()` function needs to use a custom class but it doesn’t needs to be in a class and could be embedded in the mxml file.

Comment: Well then, compose a proper class then put your **send** method into **CDATA** of the **fx:Script** tag. The class file must reside where project classpath points, the you can **import** it.

Comment: @Organis then the same problem come back. I don’t know how to call `send()` from `URLRequest.as` nor I would know how to call `MyClass` from a script tag.

Comment: Why do you need to call **send(...)** from class? What exactly do you need class for? Can't your problem (the real goal of this all) be solved, for example, without a class?

Comment: @Organis again `send()` doesn’t need to be in a class and as you can see is outside a class. But it needs to use a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I finally understand what you want to do, I've another idea - which is a little more complicated.

Create a file called **Dummy.as** and fill it with this:

```
package
{
    public class Dummy
    {
        public static function send(url:String):void
        {
            var request:Myclass=new Myclass(url);
        }
    }
}
class Myclass
{
    public function Myclass(inp:String)
    {
        trace(inp);
    }
}
```

Again, get rid of

```
<fx:Script source="URLRequest.as" />
```

and replace it by

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import Dummy;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

and finally replace

```
<s:Button x="1" y="12" label="ɢɪᴛ push !" click="send()"/>
```

with

```
<s:Button x="1" y="12" label="ɢɪᴛ push !" click="Dummy.send(txtName.text)"/>
```

The trick here is that we're importing the Dummy class that just has a static function which we can call without instantiating.
Furthermore - as long as we define it outside of the package, we can add more class definitions, which are visible to the Dummy class.

Comment: What about https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mxml/script.html?

Comment: You're referring to the _source_ attribute? Yeah, this seems like a convenient place to outsource all your
ActionScript needs. Unfortunately this ain't the original intention. As the docs say you can put in variable
and function definitions but it's **not** possible to define classes in there. It's similar to the _include_
statement.
So I'm afraid if you want to have a single file for both cases my answer above is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also not too sure what you're trying to do but here's a possible way:

Create an empty file called **Myclass.as** in the same folder as your .mxml file and insert these lines

```
package
{
    public class Myclass
    {
        public function Myclass(inp:String)
        {
            trace(inp);
        }
    }
}
```

Now get rid of

```
<fx:Script source="URLRequest.as" />
```

and replace it by

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var request:Myclass;
    public function send():void {
        request=new Myclass(txtName.text);
    }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Comment: Is there really no way to put all actionscript code in the same file ?